# Order of Object keys guaranteed or not?

Tags: javascript

If I do something like this, and then enumerate inputMenu with the loop, is it guaranteed that my for loop will return them in the order I added them? Or is this not guaranteed? Thank you.

```
inputMenu = {
            IDOD: { text: "Diam (1=ID, 0=OD)", value: null },
            DIA: { text: "Diameter", value: null },
            THK: { text: "Segment Thickness", value: null },
            PLATEWIDTH: { text: "Plate Width", value: null },
            SEG_NEUT_AXIS: { text: "MID-ARC Length", value: null } };

for (var key in inputMenu) {    
   // Will I get IDOD -> DIA -> THK -> PLATEWIDTH -> SEG_NEUT_AXIS every time?
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want guaranteed order, you should use an array. The order in which properties appear in a for in loop is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

No : the order is not specified and is implementation dependent.

From [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) :

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the
>   first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

Use an array if the order is important for you.